# Missing Scopes Required when calling Microsoft Graph from ASP .Net Core Web Api

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I have setup a web api to call from Microsoft Graph using a username/password credential passed to it via a vuejs client application. As I tried to extend it out and add new permissions (namely Team.ReadBasic.All). I get a:

`Missing scope permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All, User.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All'. Scopes on the request 'AllSites.Read, openid, profile, Tasks.ReadWrite, User.Read, User.ReadBasic.All, email'`

However I have updated my Azure Ad Application with the correct API Permissions (Delegated Team.ReadBasic.All) and I have added the scope like so

appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain",
    "TenantId": "mytenantId",
    "ClientId": "myclientId",
    "ClientSecret": "myclientsecret",
    "Scopes": "User.Read,Tasks.ReadWrite,Team.ReadBasic.All",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read,Tasks.ReadWrite,Team.ReadBasic.All"
```

With my startup using middleware to test the api.

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                options.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/v2.0";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new string[] { Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"], $"api://{Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}" };
            });

var userPassCodeCredentail = new UsernamePasswordCredential("", "", Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"], Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]);
services.AddSingleton(_ => new GraphServiceClient(userPassCodeCredentail, Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(',')));
AddSwagger(services);
```

With Add Swagger Being

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(document =>
            {
                document.AddSecurity("bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Description = "Azure AAD Authentication",
                    Flow = OpenApiOAuth2Flow.Implicit,
                    Flows = new NSwag.OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                        {
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                { $"api://{Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}/user_impersonation", "Access Application" },
                                { $"api://{Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}/Team.ReadBasic.All", "Access Team" },
                            },
                            AuthorizationUrl = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
                            TokenUrl = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                        },  
                    },
                });
                document.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));
```

Attempting to authorize this way doesn't allow me to consent to the new permission to then use the api call. As the consent panel won't appear when I complete the Microsoft page login process.

Edited: I have added the api permissions to the Azure Ad and ensured that the redirect urls and user consent is set to "Allow consent for all apps"
[image]

Comment: Did you try to comment `{ $"api://{Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}/user_impersonation", "Access Application" },` this line?

Comment: Commenting it out just removes it from scope selection when I'm doing the OpenApiOAuth2Flow. Otherwise it's just building the api link?

Comment: I'm not sure  so I just let you have a try, as you said you've set the api permission but the error message showed you didn't have the api permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the user consent settings

- Go to **Azure Active Directory** and then **Enterprise applications** from their **consent and permissions** now select **User Consent settings**
- Under User consent for applications choose the consent settings you want to provide to user
  [image]

Comment: It's currently set to "Allow user consent for apps" by default and I do not have admin access to change that. The consent screen has appeared before and I've accepted it. It just won't reappear to allow me to accept the new permissions added via the Azure AD application permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the tutorial here and ensure you have successfully completed all the steps?

[Add Azure AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3)

Comment: I reran through the steps provided here to make sure everything is hooked up correctly and it seems to be. I have no issues using the first set of permissions that the user account has consented too and can make calls to the microsoft graph user and todo api methods. It just seems to be an issue of getting the consent form to pop up when adding new permissions on the Azure Ad Application side of things